# How to add the RPM Fusion and livna repositories to Fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf, multimedia

[RPM Fusion](https://rpmfusion.org) and Livna are common [third party package repositories](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Third_party_repositories) for Fedora. You need them if you want to install media players, codecs and/or DVD playback libraries that are not part of the primary Fedora repository because of assumed issues like distribution licensing or similar.

Thus my question how to enable them in Fedora (>= 17)?

**2018 update**: For the last years, the reason d'être for the [Livna](http://rpm.livna.org/) repository was the fact that it hosted the libdvdcss package. All previous other Livna packages were migrated to rpmfusion, years ago. Since 2018, rpmfusion created the [free tainted rpmfusion repository](https://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#Free_Tainted) which **does** [include libdvdcss](https://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#How_can_I_install_libdvdcss.3F). They also provided an upgrade package that automatically removed any livna release package.

Thus, there isn't any use for Livna now. As a cautionary measure, it shouldn't be trusted anymore, in case the Livna domain expires and then is obtained by some domain grabber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For RPM Fusion (free repository):

Get the release rpm:

```
$ curl -O https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/\
rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
```

Check the archive's integrity via:

```
$ rpm --checksig rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
```

Which should fail with:

```
[..] MISSING KEYS: GPG#KEY_ID [..]
```

Add key to your gpg keyring for checking:

```
$ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys KEY_ID
```

In case the key is not available on a keyserver you have to download it from the [rpmfusion key page](https://rpmfusion.org/keys):

```
$ curl -o RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$(rpm -E %fedora) \
    'https://rpmfusion.org/\
keys?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=\
RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-'$(rpm -E %fedora)
```

Compare the fingerprint with the published information on the [RPM Fusion key site](https://rpmfusion.org/keys), via a web-search and possibly check the web of trust:

```
$ gpg --fingerprint KEY_ID
```

If successful make the key known to `rpm`:

```
$ gpg --export -a KEY_ID \
    > RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$(rpm -E %fedora)
# rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$(rpm -E %fedora)
```

Check the integrity of the package for real:

```
$ rpm --checksig rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
```

If it is ok install it:

```
# dnf install rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
```

This will create config files under `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and key files under `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg`.

Note that the `#` means that you have to execute those commands as root.

After this, to enable other rpmfusion repositories like *nonfree* or [*free tainted*](https://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#Free_Tainted) is just an install command away. For example:

```
# dnf install rpmfusion-free-release-tainted
```

This is secure, as this release package is signed by the previously verified packaging gpg key.

### Fingerprint

As the time of this writing, the rpmfusion Fedora 29 GPG key has the following fingerprint:

```
BD12 7385 C312 090F F2F3 5FA1 1191 A7C4 42F1 9ED0
```

Comment: [How to add rpm fusion testing repository in Fedora?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469334/how-to-add-rmp-fusion-testing-repository-in-fedora)

Answer (score 1):

Also, in case [livna](http://rpm.livna.org/) is not accessible (like it happened to me for a full day), you can use [ATrpms](http://atrpms.net/documentation/install/).