# How to add rpm fusion testing repository in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, rpm

This is similar question to [How to add the RPM Fusion and livna repositories to Fedora?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40856/how-to-add-the-rpm-fusion-and-livna-repositories-to-fedora) but I want to install testing repository so I can have Chromium 68. I have testing fedora repo and I need `chromium-libs-media-freeworld-68` because there is conflict, chromium-libs-media-freeworld-67 require chromium-libs-67 but chromium need 68).

I was searching https://download1.rpmfusion.org http directory and found this:

https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/updates/testing/27/x86_64/

but no rpm to use with `dnf install`. How can I install testing rpm fusion repository?

I have Fedora 27.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The updates testing branch is part of the same rpmfusion repository definition package (cf. `/etc/yum.repos.d`).

Thus you can get the 68 version like this:

```
# dnf --enablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates-testing install chromium-libs-media-freeworld
```

Or just to check:

```
# dnf --enablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates-testing list chromium-libs-media-freeworld
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:11 ago on Sun 16 Sep 2018 09:36:12 AM CEST.
Available Packages
chromium-libs-media-freeworld.x86_64 68.0.3440.106-3.fc27 rpmfusion-free-updates-testing
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used `dnf --enablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates-testing update chromium`

Comment: Just found permanent adding testing repo in [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Updates_Testing)  so for rpm fusion it will be `sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled rpmfusion-free-updates-testing`